# for loop with keys cant catch up

Tags: node.js, for-loop, request, key

i have a big object and a function that download and collects packets so it take a bit time (2-3 seconds)

the object is a json array, i can loop through it as i want with keys.

```
for(lKeay in datheData[theKeay][0]){
    
        var templKeay = lKeay;
        
        console.log(lKeay); // this logs the correct keys in order

        request({uri: datheData[theKeay][0][lKeay], followRedirect: false, followAllRedirects: false}, function (error, res, body) {
            theCounter++;
            console.log(res.headers.location + " " + templKeay); //only the last key of the object is printed
        })
}
```

The callback of the request fails to loop with for in order. As example, if the keys are `1`, `2`, `3` `console.log` inside the request callback prints `3` thrice. How can I avoid this problem. I know the callback takes time to execute but i want to know to which key that request is corresponding to. Any help ? I tried to create a temp variable `templKeay` yet still the same problem. And I can't just pass value or variables to a request function as well i guess ?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: If you have multiple callbacks, they are not guaranteed to be executed in the same order. In order to have proper order - you need to have promises and use await instead.
I would not recommend using the request library, since there are many better libraries, or at least you can use native fetch.

Comment: To execute multiple requests in parallel and still process their responses in a predefined order, use `Promise.all`, similar to the answer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73062856/getting-values-as-strings-from-database).

Answer (score 1):

Change this:

```
var templKeay = lKeay
```

to this:

```
const templKeay = lKeay;
```

And, you will have a unique value of `templKeay` for each iteration of the loop.

Or, you could also change this:

```
for(lKeay in datheData[theKeay][0])
```

to this:

```
for (const lKeay in datheData[theKeay][0])
```

And, get rid of the `templKeay` variable.

Both `let` and `const` are block-scoped whereas `var` is function scoped.  In this case, if you want a unique variable for each iteration of the loop, then you want to be sure to use `let` or `const` to declare the variable in the `for` declaration or inside the loop.

---

Note that none of this will affect the order that your `request()` operations will complete.  That will not be determinate because you are starting a whole bunch of asynchronous operations and they can finish in random order.  If you want to sequence those asynchronous `request()` operations so that they run one at a time in order, that would require a separate solution.

And finally, you should not be writing any new code using the `request()` library as the library has been [deprecated](https://github.com/request/request#deprecated) (will not be developed any more with new features and will likely be retired at some point).  You can see a list of alternatives [here](https://github.com/request/request/issues/3143) (my favorite in that list is `got()`).  Or, in the latest versions of nodejs, you can use [fetch()](https://nodejs.org/dist/latest-v18.x/docs/api/globals.html).

---

If you want to run your requests in sequence, one after the other rather than in parallel like you are now, then that will be easiest by switching to an http request library that supports promises and use `await` in the loop.